# SAPUI5 Currency not validating with model bound directly to service

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 Input component which is configured for currency.

When I enter a value, it validates fine If I tab away. for example entering 2.5 for JPY redisplays as 3.

However, I also have a save button, which performs a submitChanges() on the model (bound directly the oData service).

In this scenario, if I enter 2.5 and click save, 2.5 is incorrectly submitted to the backend.

As a workaround.. I've updated the model with the new input value via a change event on the view component, but I wondered if there was a more elegant solution?

```
 <Input value="{parts: ['rfqsService>netPrice', 'rfqsService>currency'], type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }" description="{rfqsService>currency}" change="onInputChange"/>
```

Comment: _> "if I enter 2.5 and click save, 2.5 is incorrectly submitted to the backend"_ ... Could you elaborate more on how exactly `2.5` is incorrectly submitted? What should be submitted instead? What is the EDM type of the `netPrice` entity property?

Comment: If I tab away from the price, it reforrmats 2.5 as 3 (correctly as JPY has no decimals). However if I hit the save button directly after entering 2.5, the model still contains 2.5, so the price value (3) has to be set manually in the change event method.

Comment: Is `valueLiveUpdate=true` on your Input a viable solution?

Comment: @Marc No because it means the backend auto-updated if the user enters a value. I need the button to confirm the change.